# Conditional return type based on interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a cache defined like this (snippet):

```js
interface Cache {
  chapterDates: { [workId: string]: string[] };
  kudosChecked: number[];
}

export const DEFAULT_CACHE: Cache = {
  chapterDates: {},
  kudosChecked: [],
};
```

I would like to be able to define a function that when given a cache key like 'chapterDates' or 'kudosChecked' as a string, would return the value of the cache, with the proper type of that property.

So far I've tried the following using conditional types:

```js
type Test<T> = T extends 'chapterDates'
  ? { [workId: string]: string[] }
  : T extends 'kudosChecked'
  ? number[]
  : never;

export async function getCache<T extends keyof Cache, R extends Test<T>>(
  id: T
): Promise<R> {
  [...]
}
```

I've also tried this:

```js
export async function getCache<
  T extends keyof Cache,
  R extends Cache[T]
>(id: T): Promise<R> {
  [...]
}
```

None the solutions seem to make typescript understand that when the return type of e.g. `getCache('kudosChecked')` should be `number[]`. Currently it seems to think it's `number[] | { [workId: string]: string[] }`.

Am I going about this completely wrong or something, I'm pretty new-ish to typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally figured out how to do it by going over a lot of typescript issues. The issue that helped was [microsoft/Typescript#39305](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39305). It proposes `ValueOf` as

```js
type KeyOf<
  U,
  C = unknown,
  K extends U extends unknown ? keyof U : never = U extends unknown
    ? keyof U
    : never
> = C extends unknown
  ? U extends unknown
    ? K extends unknown
      ? U[K] extends C
        ? K
        : never
      : never
    : never
  : never;

type ValueOf<U, K extends KeyOf<U> = KeyOf<U>> = U extends unknown
  ? K extends keyof U
    ? U[K]
    : never
  : never;
```

Using this new type we can then define `getCache` as so:

```js
export async function getCache<K extends CacheId, R = ValueOf<Cache, K>>(
  id: K
): Promise<R> {
  [...]
}
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=26&ssc=88&pln=25&pc=57#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmAeAqgGigYSgXigEMA7ELGKCAD2AmIBMBnKACjUprqaNKgH4oAa3gB7JFHYAuKMQgA3CACcAlPlbtqtBsxIh%20Q0eKkz5S5QD58AKCg4OW7rv0bO2nnoEVNXHbwFoAbRgAXXsfO08oaVkFRSiTWPiYpSTTRQBuKytQSCgANUIAGwBXCGR0cjC3OERUNEsCGvL6hokqxz9YduZhEDE2-yDQ6LTU2MyrAEtiWkUkQgBjaGxFgAtoAG8bKAB6HagAdRFFQQBJeihJ5kZgRWmAcyhGaaWoAHdoN8nCwqgAI2gACkAMoIAByDygwHWUHohGAhG2C1WhDAswAIvCIIxpBsoAE3sczvRpDc7sR7sFSbcHgFQgBfCa2QTFegiRjYdYLYQkmTFAC2AMUdMyzNZ7IA4pMFMRogKhSKrPSstQwMdgFDwMs1hBzmpev0VsiIBNVeqiIwQMQFlAkMVrcBJiJiFB7hBgEb1igvK5uJ7dfQsAAlNQFEplVD%208jmcwsbaTXkwKzKaQABUUIn5VwgKCDli2tj2UHTIkgcQWIno0HWimg-QrxUUjAg21rwEbLpYAHJaDcuxaoPbBMQRG8XYRfCBlJllVYWBOrTaWKo8Pmkc6brCscwCPO3oRJhq3R6dd3kaiMduu8plAEe9jgF3gqKoBXiJuWWyOVyeWo9wej3df1u0-dlOQgbkIHoa9pyVZRlyAA)